# How long did Chava (Eve) live?

Tags: history, number, historical-figures, eve-chava

The Torah tells us that Adam HaRishon lived for 930 years. Is there a source that tells us for how long Chava (Eve) lived?

I have been unable to find any source that discusses how old Chava was when she was buried. However I have heard there is a Medrash that Chanoch buried Chava. According to [Otzar Hayedios](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50454&st=&pgnum=15&hilite=) Chanoch was born in year 622 and died in the year 987. Perhaps this can help with finding an answer.

Answer (score 8):

There is a conflict in the Midrashim as to who she was buried by.

According (to the footnotes in) Seder Olam ([Bereishis 1](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/sederolam/sederolam01.pdf)) she was buried by Chanoch. This presumes that she outlived Adam.

Yet, the Sefer Tziyoni ([Vayerah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42374&st=&pgnum=36) ) writes that it was Adam, so she clearly died first.

Comment: Why does it presume she outlived Adam?

Comment: Or else Adam would have buried her. Spouses were the primary 'mourners' in those days..

Comment: Is R. Menachem Tziyoni marketed as a Midrash?

Comment: The footnote in Seder Olam is a referring to a different Girsa of Seder Olam.

Answer (score 3):

It says in Bava Basra 58a that she was buried in Hebron, but it does not say an age. And I was looking in different places to, and I do not think anyone says the age of Chava when she died, but I could be easily be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Both Yalkut Reuveni, [Parshas Chayei Sara](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19432&st=&pgnum=83&hilite=) and [Zohar 3:164a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%92_%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%93_%D7%90) doesn't mention how long Chava lived, but says that she died before Adam and he was the one who buried her.